# Alternative to expand.grid for data.frames

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `df` and I want that every row in this `df` is duplicated `lengthTime` times and that a new column is added that counts from 1 to `lengthTime` for each row in `df`.

I know, it sounds pretty complicated, but what I basically want is to apply `expand.grid` to `df`. Here is an ugly workaround and I have the feeling that there most be an easier solution (maybe even a base-R function?):

```
df <- data.frame(ID   = rep(letters[1:3], each=3),
                 CatA = rep(1:3, times = 3),
                 CatB = letters[1:9])
lengthTime <- 3
nrRow <- nrow(df)
intDF <- df
for (i in 1:(lengthTime - 1)) {
  df <- rbind(df, intDF)
}
df$Time <- rep(1:lengthTime, each=nrRow)
```

I thought that I could just use `expand.grid(df, 1:lengthTime)`, but that does not work. `outer` did not bring any luck either. So does anyone know a good solution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not just something like `df[rep(1:nrow(df),times = 3),]` to extend the data frame, and then add the extra column just as you have above, with `df$Time <- rep(1:lengthTime, each=nrRow)`?

Answer (score 66):

It's been a while since this question was posted, but I recently came across it looking for just the thing in the title, namely, an `expand.grid` that works for data frames. The posted answers address the OP's more specific question, so in case anyone is looking for a more general solution for data frames, here's a slightly more general approach:

```
expand.grid.df <- function(...) Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by=NULL), list(...))

# For the example in the OP
expand.grid.df(df, data.frame(1:lengthTime))

# More generally
df1 <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=11:13)
df2 <- data.frame(C=51:52, D=c("Y", "N"))
df3 <- data.frame(E=c("+", "-"))
expand.grid.df(df1, df2, df3)
```

Comment: Worked really nice ... I used this method for [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42112654/10059841), in my solution here: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808294/10059841)

Answer (score 27):

You can also just do a simple `merge` by `NULL` (which will cause `merge` to do simple combinatorial data replication):

```
merge(data.frame(time=1:lengthTime), iris, by=NULL)
```

Comment: I like this solution the most but for the sake of simplicity (avoiding dependencies) you could have just wrote `merge(data.frame(time=1:lengthTime), iris, by=NULL)`

Answer (score 13):

Quick update

There is now also the crossing() function in package tidyr which can be used instead of merge, is somewhat faster, and returns a tbl_df / tibble.

```
data.frame(time=1:10) %>% merge(iris, by=NULL) 

data.frame(time=1:10) %>% tidyr::crossing(iris)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
REP <- rep(1:nrow(df), 3)
df2 <- data.frame(df[REP, ], Time = rep(1:3, each = 9))
rownames(df2) <- NULL
df2
```

Comment: Mine really isn't any different than joran's who beat me by 40 some seconds but I'll leave it as it's slightly more explicit.

Comment: First come, first serve, so I accepted his answer ;-) But +1 for both of you. That's a very neat solution!

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution:

```
> library(data.table)
>  ( df <- data.frame(ID   = rep(letters[1:3], each=3),
+                  CatA = rep(1:3, times = 3),
+                  CatB = letters[1:9]) )
  ID CatA CatB
1  a    1    a
2  a    2    b
3  a    3    c
4  b    1    d
5  b    2    e
6  b    3    f
7  c    1    g
8  c    2    h
9  c    3    i
> ( DT <- data.table(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) rep(x,3))][, Time:=rep(1:3, each=nrow(df0))] )
    ID CatA CatB Time
 1:  a    1    a    1
 2:  a    2    b    1
 3:  a    3    c    1
 4:  b    1    d    1
 5:  b    2    e    1
 6:  b    3    f    1
 7:  c    1    g    1
 8:  c    2    h    1
 9:  c    3    i    1
10:  a    1    a    2
11:  a    2    b    2
12:  a    3    c    2
13:  b    1    d    2
14:  b    2    e    2
15:  b    3    f    2
16:  c    1    g    2
17:  c    2    h    2
18:  c    3    i    2
19:  a    1    a    3
20:  a    2    b    3
21:  a    3    c    3
22:  b    1    d    3
23:  b    2    e    3
24:  b    3    f    3
25:  c    1    g    3
26:  c    2    h    3
27:  c    3    i    3
```

Another one :

```
> library(data.table)
>  ( df <- data.frame(ID   = rep(letters[1:3], each=3),
+                  CatA = rep(1:3, times = 3),
+                  CatB = letters[1:9]) )
> DT <- data.table(df)
> rbindlist(lapply(1:3, function(i) cbind(DT, Time=i)))
    ID CatA CatB Time
 1:  a    1    a    1
 2:  a    2    b    1
 3:  a    3    c    1
 4:  b    1    d    1
 5:  b    2    e    1
 6:  b    3    f    1
 7:  c    1    g    1
 8:  c    2    h    1
 9:  c    3    i    1
10:  a    1    a    2
11:  a    2    b    2
12:  a    3    c    2
13:  b    1    d    2
14:  b    2    e    2
15:  b    3    f    2
16:  c    1    g    2
17:  c    2    h    2
18:  c    3    i    2
19:  a    1    a    3
20:  a    2    b    3
21:  a    3    c    3
22:  b    1    d    3
23:  b    2    e    3
24:  b    3    f    3
25:  c    1    g    3
26:  c    2    h    3
27:  c    3    i    3
```