# Summarise no longer grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

I think dplyr is awesome.  However I recently updated the package and it seems that summarise no longer aggregates by group for me.  Something similar to the following code used to summarize by group before the upgrade:

```
iris_tdt <- tbl_dt(iris)
iris_tdt %.% group_by(Species) %.% summarise(avg_petal_width = mean(Petal.Width))

  avg_petal_width
1        1.199333
```

This used to output a table with Species and avg_petal_width.  Now the Species column seems to be dropped and avg_petal_width is aggregated to a single value.  group_by seems to be working, so I'm guessing this is a issue with summarise.

```
grp <- group_by(iris_tdt,Species)
groups(grp)

[[1]]
Species
```

Not even the example from the Vignette works correctly.

```
hflights_df <- tbl_df(hflights)
planes <- group_by(hflights_df, TailNum)
delay <- summarise(planes,
  dist = mean(Distance, na.rm = TRUE),
  delay = mean(ArrDelay, na.rm = TRUE))

delay
      dist    delay
1 787.7832 7.094334
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
packageDescription("dplyr")$Version #--> 0.1.2
R.version.string #--> "R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this (with the same R and dplyr versions). Have you checked in a clean R session?

Comment: Hi @joran, thanks for the comment.  You are on the right track, when I started a clean R version the vignette code worked but I saw the error again when I ran my script.  Turns out Vincent had the full solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have another `summarise` function, 
probably from the `plyr` package.

```
# Works
library(dplyr)
iris_tdt <- tbl_dt(iris)
iris_tdt %.% 
  group_by(Species) %.% 
  summarise(avg_petal_width = mean(Petal.Width))

# No longer works...
library(plyr)
iris_tdt <- tbl_dt(iris)
iris_tdt %.% 
  group_by(Species) %.% 
  summarise(avg_petal_width = mean(Petal.Width))
```

If you really need both packages,
you can try to load `dplyr` last,
or prefix all the affected functions (`summarise`, `mutate`, etc.)
with their namespace (`dplyr::summarise`, etc.)

Comment: That must have been it!  I was using the expand.grid.df package in reshape, and it was loading plyr in the background.  I turned that off and used an alternative expand.grid.df (found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693599/alternative-to-expand-grid-for-data-frames) by YT.  Works perfectly now.  Thank you!