# How to get the combinations of multiple vectors in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame `x`. I want to get the pairwise combinations of all rows, like `(x[1,], x[2,)`, `(x[1,], x[3,])`, `(x[2,], x[3,])`. Here I take each row as an entirety. I tried functions like `combn`, but it gave me the combinations of all elements in all rows.

Comment: Something like `expand.grid(1:2, 1:2)`?

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. Refer to "How to make a Great Reproducible Example" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I think with `combn` you are on the right track:

```
x <- data.frame(a=sample(letters, 10), b=1:10, c=runif(10), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ans <- combn(nrow(x), 2, FUN=function(sub) x[sub,], simplify=FALSE)
```

Now `ans` is a list of (in this case 45, in general `choose(nrow(x), 2)`) data.frames with two rows each.

Answer (score 0):

The [crossing() function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38974695/534238) from the tidyr package may help you.  (The link contains a StackOverflow example.)